# Búsqueda en datatable con jquery uncaught typeerror search is not a function

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente código Javascript, mi idea es realizar un filtrado por el téxto de cada uno de los botones, tengo dos botones para filtrar, el primero con texto X y el segundo con texto Y, quiero que al pulsar en cada botón se busque en el datatable si hay alguna entrada que aparezca el texto X o el texto Y que aparece en los botones. 
Mi código de jquery es el siguiente :

```
$(".botonesTabla").on('click', function () {
    //console.log(this.textContent);
    tabla.search(this.textContent);

});
```

Esto sería el código que hay en botones:

```
 @foreach (var t in Unalista)
                    {
                        string labelTipo = "ct-label-" + t.unID;

                        <button type="button" class="btn labelTipo ct-btn-filter @labelTipo botonesTabla" data-target="@t.otroID" >@t.Nombre</button>

                    }
```

No se que es lo que falla, alguien me puede ayudar, soy bastante nuevo.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te está diciendo que el objeto `tabla` no contiene ningún método `search`. Comprueba que tabla es el objeto que esperas (sin más información no podemos ayudarte mucho)

Comment: El objeto tabla es el esperado y según me pude informar si que contiene ese método

Comment: Sería un objeto datatable que si contiene search

Comment: tabla = $("#idtabla").DataTable();

Comment: Qué versión del plugin datatables estás usando? Las versiones anteriores a la 1.10 no tienen el método search

Comment: Mi versión es esta: DataTables 1.10.16

Comment: Curioso: el error deja claro que tabla no es undefined, pero no tiene el método search. ¿Si pones `console.log(tabla.search)` muestra algo?

Comment: Esa línea de código me devuelve: ƒ (){var d=b.apply(a,arguments);s.extend(d,d,c.methodExt);return d}